# Big INT in MySql returning a row when the value is set 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySql where the data type of a column (external_id) is set to 'bigint' data type of length (20)

Column : external_id,bigint(20)

Table: Order_table

```
product name external_id
Drink   Coke  0
Drink   Pepsi 12342
Grain   Wheat 42345
```

When i run the below select statement

> select * from order_table where external_id = 'test'

```
Output:

product name external_id
Drink   Coke  0
```

How is it possible that the above query returns a row when i had external_id = 'test' ?

Any thoughts. Many thanks for the help

Comment: in short any string is converted to 0 when matching against an int

Comment: Question is, why would you want to search for an alphanumeric value in a bigint field?

Comment: i guess the php part would be to check that an integer is used in the search `is_int()`

Comment: @Dagon : Thanks for the explanation.. "  any string is converted to 0 when matching against an int " solves the mystery .. I am running a report where the external_id gets populated from a table which get updated dynamically based on some user interactions..